# Создать еще одно приложение или расширить функционал существующего

Tags: архитектура

Всем привет.
Есть приложение - сервер на Express, REST API - осуществляет продажи на одном из маркетплэйсов, обслуживая запросы маркетплэйса. Также служит как апи для админки. Взаимодействует с БД на Монго.
Хотим создать свой веб-магазин. Магазин хотелось бы реализовать на websocket. Кажется правильным привязать магазин к существующей БД, так как в ней уже ведется учет товаров. Встает вопрос как правильно реализовать АПИ для магазина. Вижу два пути:

1. Расширить функционал существующего приложения. Вроде можно в одном приложение реализовать параллельно REST API и Websocket.
2. Написать новое приложение с Websocket, которое будет взаимодействовать с той же БД Монго.

Вопрос.
Каким из путей пойти?

Comment: Взаимодействие двух разных приложений с одной БД — сомнительный подход, потому что случайная рассинхронизация кода, связанного с работой с этой БД, создаёт риск всё сломать

Comment: Традиционный подход во всех крупных бизнесах -- это множество приложений, работающих с общей СУБД

Comment: @avp и как вносить изменения в эту СУБД, не сломав при этом сразу всё? Особенно если это Монго...

Comment: @andreymal, про Монго я ничего не знаю. А традиционные СУБД (и систему их программирования-администрирования) создают таким образом, чтобы приложения (конечно, правильно отлаженные) ничего не ломали. / Собственно, тут та же ситуация что с сетью (созданной грамотными инженерами) и вебом (сделанным толпой дилетантов)

Comment: @andreymal А что может поломаться?
Приложения независимые. Что там может рассинхронизироваться?

Comment: @Vasily вот в том и проблема что независимые. Изменили формат хранения данных в СУБД в одном приложении — а в другом приложении забыли изменить, и в итоге оно больше не может работать с этой СУБД и ломается

Comment: @andreymal Понимаю. Это некоторая доп. сложность. Нужно помнить о том что приложений 2 при изменении базы.
Какие еще могут быть сложности?